# How can I put in the "@" sign on your Stack Exchange log In from a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, operating-systems, keyboard

When I try to log in with my stack exchange credentials from a raspberry pi, the keyboard registers a quotes sign (") instead of an "@" (at) sign.  I'm using an Epiphany browser in a Raspbian OS.

Comment: Have you checked that your keyboard layout is correct?  It's probably not if you did not change it when you first installed.

Answer (score 4):

You have a UK English keyboard layout set on your RPi.  From [this site](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Re-mapping_the_keyboard_with_Debian_Squeeze), you have two options.

### Option 1

Run the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Follow the prompts. Then restart your RasPi.

### Option 2

Run the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
```

Find the entry `XKBLAYOUT="gb"` and change `gb` with, likely `us`.

### Restart

Run the command:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't have to try option 2.  sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration WORKED Fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info, I found the "quick & dirty trick" for substitution on the U.S. keyboard layout is shift + double quotes (") to display the @ sign.