# How do you reconfigure the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I just installed Noobs on my Raspberry Pi and every thing was going well until I tried to use a pipe (|) in the terminal.  When I pressed the key, It wrote different characters!  I tried a few more key combos and discovered that the ~`@# and a few other characters were either assigned to a different key or missing.  I am assuming that I have that works keyboard layout set.  How do I change this?

Comment: You might have to search a bit for the simplest answer in the duplicate post.  To summarise use sudo raspi-config and the Internationalisation option if you are using Raspbian.

Comment: Check out my answer to this question here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33524/how-can-i-put-in-the-sign-on-your-stack-exchange-log-in-from-a-raspberry-pi/33525#33525